# Access with Azure Automation in Blob Storage

Tags: powershell, azure, blob-storage

I have 3 BlobStorage in Azure with limited access with a Virtual network, I would you like run script with AzureAutomation that will snapshot objects into accounts.

But when I do a test pan I have a problem access. So I tought Azure's IP Public in my location (WestEurope), I thought the added in Firewall's Blob Storage but there are 110 Ip range. the problem is that I can't add more than 100 in firewall's blobStorage.

So how I can do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Storage Endpoints to restrict access to your storage account then it is going to be difficult to add access for Azure Automation directly, as you saw there are a large number of possible IP ranges and they increase regularly.

Your best option would be to run an [Azure Automation hybrid worker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) inside your vNet. That way you can still run your jobs through Azure Automation, but they will execute inside your vNet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try your solution and I come back. Thanks Again !